# Intellij IDEA code coverage doesn't work

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea, code-coverage

When I'm trying to run my JUnit tests with coverage I receive the following error

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:382)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:397)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.coverage.main.CoveragePremain.premain(CoveragePremain.java:50)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.intellij.rt.coverage.instrumentation.Instrumentator.premain(Instrumentator.java:40)
    ... 11 more
Exception in thread "main" 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anybody help to fix it?

Comment: Is this specific to a particular test code? Do your tests work without code coverage enabled?

Comment: I checked it with different pieces of code and with different Intellij versions. I always receive the same result. Yes, tests work without coverage.

Comment: Did you tried change the code coverage runner? Could you post here the code coverage configuration?

Comment: Anatoly, were you able to solve this? I am getting the same issue while using JaCoCo for code coverage for android?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5941

You can add -Djava.io.tmpdir param to idea's launching script or replace TMP system property.

Also probably you will have to change idea.config.path and idea.system.path in idea.properties in installation directory.