# Cannot run testings using intellij jupiter

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage, junit5

I am in the last steps in completing my java project in intelij.
Now trying to test to system and it done successfully[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qawhp.png)

until I'm running the tests with coverage
then getting this error(even not compiled)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yOGU.png)

java version - 1.8.0_251
testings tool supported by intellij and not jacoco or emma.
testings version - Junit5/jupiter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj1Aj.png)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907103/intellij-idea-code-coverage-doesnt-work

Comment: @AntonBelev checked already and didn't solve my problem...

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after reproducing the issue and full classpath from run output?

Comment: @y.bedrov Is it the reason that I have 2 log files: idea.log.1 and idea.log.2? I have attached screenshots in the question above.

Comment: @y.bedrov 2020-04-29 19:41:57,574 [2371077]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed. 
2020-04-29 19:41:57,580 [2371083]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\�?�?��\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\log\build-log\build.log (The system cannot find the path specified) 
2020-04-29 19:41:57,580 [2371083]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)

Comment: As mentioned in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5941 issue is caused by non-unicode characters in path. Please try workaround from YouTrack.